# Lest and the continuous infinitive?

Tags: infinitives

Is it OK to use LEST with the continuous infinitive?

> Give her something to eat lest she be crying.

I think it's correct.

Comment: The basic syntax of ***lest*** in imperative utterances like your example is ***Do this lest that happens*** (rarely, subjunctive *...lest that [**should**] **happen***). Hence it would be *Give her something to eat lest she cries / lest she [should] cry*. But that's probably not what you intended anyway - more likely what you were trying to say was *Give her something to eat **if** she cries* (feed her *after / if and when she starts crying*, not *in order to prevent her crying*). As a general principle though, you should probably avoid ***lest***, since it's increasingly falling into disuse.

Comment: I would understand it to mean _...in case she is crying_; which would be better expressed using "if". **Lest** usually suggests something that may happen in the future. So "...lest she cry/cries" would be more suitable here.

Comment: Actually, I very much meant what you thought I didn't,  FumbleFingers.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that your phrasing makes it ambiguous since we do not know whether the crying is ongoing or whether it is a future hypothetical event. Since *lest* is a rather uncommon word it might be better to re-phrase it.

> Give her something to eat so she doesn't start crying.

would work or if she is currently crying

> Give her something to eat to stop her crying.

Comment: Since when is LEST an uncommon word? Maybe in your personal vocabulary only.

Comment: @user1425 Since the 1800s: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=lest&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3

Comment: [Cambridge Advanced Learner's Dictionary & Thesaurus](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/lest) calls lest "literary". It's certainly not part of everyday vocabulary.